# F1 score graph skewed

Tags: matplotlib, f1score

The following code

```
DBSCAN_score = pd.read_csv("DBSCAN_scores.csv")
sigmoid_score = pd.read_csv("Sigmoid_scores.csv")

score = pd.concat([sigmoid_score.F1_score.fillna(0), DBSCAN_score.F1_score.fillna(0)], axis=1)
score.columns = ["Sigmoid", "DBSCAN"]
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_title("F1 score comparison")
score.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Normaly I would get the output bellow
[image]

Now I am getting the following result with the same code and the same files.
I'm struggling to make it look like the output above

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it is because some reason your x limits is different, you could try:

```py
plt.xlim(0,120)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some explanation for why you are suggesting this change.

Comment: If you see the x limits, in figure 1 they are bt [0,120] and in figure 2 bt [0,350], the figure might be the same, it is just a configuration of the plots